# JPA to Hibernate mapping

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, hibernate-mapping

i have an existing application EJB,OpenJPA where below mapping is working fine and when i migrated to springboot hibernate it gives error as `broken id` tried sevaral example but not found solution any help would be appreciable.

```
public class Table1{
    @EmbeddedId
    private Table1PK id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "t1k1", referencedColumnName = "t2k1")
    private Table2 table2;

 }
```

And the PK for Table1 is as follows:

```
public class Table1PK implements Serializable{

    private String t1k1;
    private String t1k2;
    .
    .
    //other keys
}
```

And Child Table is as follows:

```
public class Table2 {
    @EmbeddedId
    private Table2PK id;
    //other fields
}
```

And the PK for Table2 is as follows:

```
public class Table2PK implements Serializable{
   private String t2k1;
   private String t2k2;

 }
```

Below is the stack trace with above implementation:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: broken column mapping for: table2.id of: com.org.model.Table2
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.initPropertyPaths(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:304) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.initIdentifierPropertyPaths(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:392) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.initPropertyPaths(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:358) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.initOrdinaryPropertyPaths(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2428) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.initPropertyPaths(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2475) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.postConstruct(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4083) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:446) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor85.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:96) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:77) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.initialize(MetamodelImpl.java:154) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:295) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:467) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:939) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) ~[spring-orm-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
```

====================

## Table is as follows:

**Table1**

```
id|name|age|emailId|
```

where composite key is id and age

**Table2:**

```
id|address1|address2|pincode|
```

where composte key is id and pincode
and this is absolutely onetoone mapping for each record in Table1 there will or will not be record in Table2 Since it is not mandatory that each person should have address but if address is there id will be same in both the tables.

And id is not Autoincrement or int it is customized as per the requirement.

Comment: More information about the exception being thrown is needed. What type of an exception is it exactly? A stack trace would also be helpful.

Comment: @PiotrPodraza thanks for the response added stacktrace it's killing me

Comment: does table2pk have the @Embeddable annotation?

Comment: @imperezivan yes Table2PK is also having `@Embeddable` annotation

Comment: Can you please post the whole stacktrace?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli i already posted

Answer (score 0):

Table2 has a composed id, so table2 attribute require double JoinColumn annotation, I've changed the property insertable and updatable as false, because this columns are already mapped in `Table1PK id`;

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "t1k1", referencedColumnName = "t2k1", , insertable = false, updatable = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "t1k2", referencedColumnName = "t2k2", , insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Table2 table2;
```

Comment: thanks for the info but in t1k2 and t2k2 is not same i mean there is no relationship between those two keys t1k2 is dependent on table1 and t2k2 is dependent on table the only common thing between those two t1k1 and t2k1 from which i am trying to join.

Comment: if table1 can have a record with t1k1 = 'x' and in table2 can have multiple rows with t2k1 = 'x' but different t2k2 values, you have a oneToMany relationship, Could you please post an example of your tables content?